# Displaying text if it has votes in sort program

Tags: java

I have a voting program that works. The program will ask the user to enter the votes for a vote candidate, and then once ended the program will print a summary of the votes.

Currently i have the program printing First,Second, and Third. Even if Second and third are 0. I need the program to work so if second and third are zero, only the winner will be printed.

I am little stuck with what i have currently, the concept i want works, but if i place the displayed text in the loop, it will loop multiple times.

here is the code

```html
System.out.print("\nThird: ");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    if (Array[i] != 0 && Array[i] == thirdScore) {
        System.out.print(stringArray[i]+" ");
    }
}
System.out.print("\n");

System.out.print("Second: ");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    if (Array[i] != 0 && Array[i] == secondScore) {
       System.out.print(stringArray[i]+" ");
    }
}
System.out.print("\n");

System.out.print("Winner: ");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    if (Array[i] != 0 && Array[i] == firstScore) {
      System.out.print(stringArray[i]+" ");
    }
}
System.out.print("\n");
```

This is the output i would get if the third place is 0

```
Third place:

Second Place: Joey

First Place: Miles
```

I need the "Third place:" to not be displayed if 0 same with Second place

Comment: Where Array was defined? what does it contain ?

Comment: array at start is initialised with 5 values (0,0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have apparently already identified the highest votes counts you can test these for zero before trying to look up the corresponding name(s) in the parallel array.

```
if (0 != thirdScore) {
  ... look up and print third place
}
if (0 != secondScore) {
  ... look up and print second place
}
```